# I've implemented a bouncing ball using html5 canvas, but can't figure out how to make the ball rotate at the same time

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to implement a bouncing element around the edges of the viewport. I've successfully implemented the bouncing mechanism, but can't figure out how to make it rotate accordingly. Any help is appreciated!

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Ls6e7wy/3/)

```
function Ball (radius, color) {
  if (radius === undefined) { radius = 50; }
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.rotation = 0;
  this.scaleX = 1;
  this.scaleY = 1;
  this.color = "#000";
}

Ball.prototype.draw = function (context) {
  context.save();
  context.translate(this.x, this.y);
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(0, 0, this.radius, 0, (Math.PI * 2), true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();

  context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";x
  context.font="12px Arial";
  context.fillText("Lorem Ipsum",0,0);
  context.restore();
};
```

Comment: `context.translate`... Hmmm, that sounds suspiciously interesting. Translations are one type of transformation, rotations are another. The two can be combined. The order of transformations will affect the final result..  (Hint: translate first)

Comment: Can you clarify? I'm really stuck :(

Comment: The canvas will combine a number of separate transforms in order to place the objects at the desired location with the desired size and orientation. It does this by combining all of the seperate operations into a single operation to be performed. It does so with the help of matrix multiplication.. What happened when you tried to add `context.rotate( 45 * 3.141/180)` immediately after the call to `context.translate`? You did try that, right!?